# Passing filtering options to a nested serializer in django DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

assuming I have the following models and serializers :

Models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks', 
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()
```

and the following serializers :

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

I would like to write a view that by getting a duration value will return a list of albums containing the tracks that the duration is equal to the given duration value.

Assuming I have an album :

```
a - of John,
  track1, duration : 60
  track2, duration : 120
  track3, duration : 60

b- of Mike,
  track1, duration : 60
  track2, duration : 120
```

If I'll reach my endpoint with the value duration: 60, I want the following to return:

```
[album : a,  
  track1, duration : 60
  track2, duration : 120
  track3, duration : 60
 album : b,
  track1, duration : 1:00
]
```

The main issue I am having is that I can't control the queryset of a nested serializer, what I would like to be able to do, is to pass the duration value somehow to the nested TrackSerializer and using a ListSerializer or similar to control the filtering.

Comment: i don't understand your desire result properly. Can you please elaborate more.